# How to highlight newly replaced text in vim

Tags: vim, replace, highlight

After I do a replace, I'd like vim to highlight the text that has just been changed (instead of the words that match my search). Say, if I type `s/old/new/`, I want `new` to be highlighted (instead of `old`). Is there any ways to do that?

I thought about triggering a search on `new` after the replace step but that would also highlight the  words that were already in the text before.

Comment: I think it's not possible easily. A plugin could be written for this, but unless i miss something, it would need (quite some) time to write

Answer (score 1):

If you only want highlighting of those instances that were replaced (not all `new` ones), you have to write your own `:Substitute` command that records each change position (via `:help sub-replace-expr`), and then builds a regular expression that only matches at those positions (using `\%l` and `\%c`). Doable, but quite involved.

You probably know this feature from other editors; try to live without it, it's not essential.

Answer (score 0):

The command separator in vim is |

You can run the search after the replace in the same line

`:s/old/new/ | /new`

Comment: Thanks, this is nice start, but as I said, this would also highlight all the `new` words that were in the text before. Say if I run this command on the line `old new`, every word will be highlighted while I only want to highlight the first one.